# Help me identify the window manufacturer please

Tags: windows

I can't find any stickers only codes and numbers etched on the glass. Here is a pic and all that is etched on the corner of the windows. Can't figure out how to identify the manufacturer. Please help if you can!

Tempered UA
16 OFR 1201 11
ANSi z97 . 1 2009
cc-10 10/30/13

There's a chance one of the numbers or letters is wrong as I'm trying to read it upside down or backwards so I included a pic of that as well.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think the sticker is for the glass only, not the window manufacturer.

Comment: Usually, the manufacturer information is in the track and/or on the edges of the sashes on single- or double-hung windows. That, however, is neither of those... Have you looked up at the very top? They may have left one sticker up there, hidden behind the shade's valence.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? It's often better to ask about that.

Comment: Yes, I will keep looking inside the tracks but haven't found a sticker yet. We have water or moisture seeping in and need to check on the window's warranty to inquire about a potential window failure or not. That's why I want to know the manufacturer. Thanks yes it does appear to be just glass info. thanks!